# Debugging PHP Error: Ajax Chat installation

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

Unable to run install script for Ajax chat.  It appears that the function calls can find the appropriate $filename, so I am having trouble determining what the invalid argument is.

```
in file [ROOT]/phpbb/di/container_builder.php on line 291: file_put_contents(C:/inetpub/wwwroot/phpbb3/chat/../cache/container_C:/inetpub/wwwroot/phpbb3/chatslashdotdotslash.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

Here is line 284-291:

```
protected function dump_container($container_filename)
{
    $dumper = new PhpDumper($this->container);
    $cached_container_dump = $dumper->dump(array(
        'class'         => 'phpbb_cache_container',
        'base_class'    => 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder',
    ));
    file_put_contents($container_filename, $cached_container_dump);
}
```

The function call for $container_filename is

```
protected function get_container_filename()
{
    $filename = str_replace(array('/', '.'), array('slash', 'dot'), $this->phpbb_root_path);
    return $this->phpbb_root_path . 'cache/container_' . $filename . '.' . $this->php_ext;
}
```

The function variable for $cached_container_dump is what I think may be the issue, as shown above in line 2. I'm not sure base_class is being found because it is not in the namespace. Been trying to follow this for a few days... any help will be appreciated.

Results from var_dump($dumper) here: does this mean the array is returning an object?

```
object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Dumper\PhpDumper)#13 (7) { ["inlinedDefinitions":"Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Dumper\PhpDumper":private]=> object(SplObjectStorage)#3325 (1) { ["storage":"SplObjectStorage":private]=> array(198)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `file_put_contents` function with the one below:

```
file_put_contents($container_filename, $cached_container_dump, FILE_APPEND);
```

And make sure that `$dumper->dump()` function returns a string.

Comment: Hmm. I have made the change to the function, but I am unclear about the $dumper-> dump(). It looks like it returns an array, but I guess I will have to track down the 'base_class' because I am not really sure what that array is setting up there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the colon it the cache file name since it's not a valid file name character on windows.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I do not see a colon in any cache file names?

Comment: You generate the `$filename` variable from `$this->phpbb_root_path` which seems to contain `c:` as is the error message you can see `.../cache/container_C:/inetpub/...`. It's also interesting that it still contains slashes although you tried to replace them. Maybe you should check if `get_container_filename()` is called and if so what's the content of `$filename` after setting it.